# Airflow attempts to kill spawned docker containers but containers live on

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

We are using Airflow for job scheduling. To run our code in an isolated environment, we have Airflow spawn jobs via the BashOperator and docker-compose. So each airflow task creates a container. This works well but we noticed a problem with jobs that are prematurely terminated.

When a job is, for example, set to failed in the airflow web interface, the log indicates that a SIGTERM was sent and that the process no longer exists. Airflow and its components are themselves running in docker containers (see docker-compose below). Looking at the Airflow-worker container, we see that the process indeed has been killed.

However, when looking at docker ps, we see that the docker container is actually still alive! Obviously this is very dangerous, as potentially long-running tasks that are no longer running according to the airflow GUI are in fact eating up resources.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Airflow Version 2.4.3
We use this docker-compose.yml to deploy the different airflow components  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution for our problem.

There is now a `DockerOperator` available in Airflow as a provider which handles stopping and removing docker containers.

Main code:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py
Example:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-docker/3.0.0/tests/system/providers/docker/example_docker_copy_data.py